# Javascript playing with object items

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm having 2 sets of object, an example:

```
var objA = {};
    objA.data1a = 100;
    objA.data2a = 70;
    objA.data3a = 16;
    objA.data4a = 37;
    objA.data5a = 88;
  //my ObjA will contain the following
  //{"data1a":100, "data2a":70, ......... "data5a":88}

var objB = {}
    objA.data1b = 19;
    objA.data2b = 5;
    objA.data3b = 7;
    objA.data4b = 6;
    objA.data5b = 2;

var getDifferences = {};

//I want to get the differences using a loop but I'm not sure how am I able to do so.
//I am able to do this currently
// getDifferences.data1 = objA.data1a - objB.data1b;
// getDifferences.data2 = objA.data2a - objB.data2b;
// getDifferences.data3 = objA.data3a - objB.data3b;
```

may I know if there's a loop to loop through an object so that for each loop I can minus and store the differences into another object?

Comment: you may consider a better iterable structure like an array and not an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iteration over the keys. I assume, that `objB` should contain the other values.

```js
var objA = { data1a: 100, data2a: 70, data3a: 16, data4a: 37, data5a: 88 },
    objB = { data1b: 19, data2b: 5, data3b: 7, data4b: 6, data5b: 2 },
    getDifferences = {};

Object.keys(objA).forEach(function (k) {
    var kk = k.substring(0, k.length - 1);
    getDifferences[kk] = objA[kk + 'a'] - objB[kk + 'b'];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getDifferences, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

More Example

> What if.. my naming were different? EXAMPLE: var storeA = {}; {"1000": 532, "2020": 123} and var storeB = {}; {"1000": 200, "2020": 12}

```js
var storeA = {"1000": 532, "2020": 123},
    storeB = {"1000": 200, "2020": 12},
    getDifferences = {};

Object.keys(storeA).forEach(function (k) {
    getDifferences[k] = storeA[k] - storeB[k];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getDifferences, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Even more Example

> in storeX obj and storeY obj. { '4100': 3060431, '4130': 4413045, '16386': 4191921, '17476': 4161761 } { '4100': 3332286, '4130': 7640173, '16386': 5773080, '17476': 4692493 }

```js
var storeA = { '4100': 3060431, '4130': 4413045, '16386': 4191921, '17476': 4161761 },
    storeB = { '4100': 3332286, '4130': 7640173, '16386': 5773080, '17476': 4692493 },
    getDifferences = {};

Object.keys(storeA).forEach(function (k) {
    getDifferences[k] = Math.abs(storeA[k] - storeB[k]);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getDifferences, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks. What if.. my naming were different?

EXAMPLE: var storeA = {};

{"1000": 532, "2020": 123}

and var storeB = {};

{"1000": 200, "2020": 12}

Comment: then you could map it directly.

Comment: I think it will be easier if I just list down the exact data I have.

Comment: I have this 2 set of data which i'm trying to get it to dynamically stores the differences.

Comment: in storeX obj and storeY obj.

{ '4100': 3060431, '4130': 4413045, '16386': 4191921, '17476': 4161761 }
{ '4100': 3332286, '4130': 7640173, '16386': 5773080, '17476': 4692493 }

Comment: please see above, i included the last question to the answer.

Comment: Is it okay to add this in your code?

Math.abs(getDifferences[k] = storeX[k] - storeY[k]);

Comment: `Math.abs(..)` goes on the rigth side of the assignment, please see above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110608/discussion-between-yubin-qiu-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you actually can do this using Object.keys() function.
Here is my example to do this:

```
var objA = {};
    objA.data1a = 100;
    objA.data2a = 70;
    objA.data3a = 16;
    objA.data4a = 37;
    objA.data5a = 88;
  //my ObjA will contain the following
  //{"data1a":100, "data2a":70, ......... "data5a":88}

var objB = {}
    objB.data1b = 19;
    objB.data2b = 5;
    objB.data3b = 7;
    objB.data4b = 6;
    objB.data5b = 2;

var getDifferences = {};

/// =================

var keysA = Object.keys(objA);
var keysB = Object.keys(objB);

if (keysA.length == keysB.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < keysA.length; i++) {
        getDifferences['data'+i] = objA[keysA[i]] - objB[keysB[i]];
    }
}

console.log(getDifferences);
```